# Disputed flag after user edit

Tags: discussion, flags, moderation, disputed-flags

I've flagged today the following answer as **not an answer**:

```
Please can you help me ?

Why this is not working ? 

USER CODE HERE

I am not getting any replay from the Google.. What am i doing wrong ?

Thank you!
```

But this flag has status **disputed**

I think the problem here is because after my flagging this post, user answer was completely edited in the following way:

```
Just wanted to share: I make a little change because the code above didn't worked for me: This line was a problem

CODE HERE

this is the full code of php google bigquery auth and php google bigquery insert that works for me:

CODE HERE
```

Is this correct? I think such flag should be removed when user edits his post and the flag hasn't been reviewed yet or moderator should consider this flag for the revision of post that was during my flagging post and not the modified answer that makes the thing completely different

Comment: disputed != declined.  Disputed means several community members disagreed with you.  Declined is when the moderators declined your flag.  Disputed flags don't mean anything.  They don't count against you.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I get it, but it's quite possible that moderators reviewed the flag AFTER editing answer by user so the probably looked at quite different answer that I flagged. And looking at the post in my question - could be any other reason they disagree this post was not an answer?

Comment: It was [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26958820/578411), right?

Comment: @rene Yes, it was that

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek my point is who cares.  It is a disputed flag, it doesn't mean anything.  Doesn't hurt your flag score at all, so it won't lead to a ban.  It seems dangerous to automatically dismiss flags because of an edit (how do you know the edit was actually going to be good enough).

Comment: @psubsee2003 You can also get your flags declined in exactly the same scenario. If a moderator looks at it after a previous non-answer was edited into an answer, they will decline it.

Comment: @RetoKoradi I won't dispute that but that wasn't the issue here.  In the big picture, if you are a responsible flagger, one declined flag won't be an issue

Comment: @psubsee2003 Certainly. It's rare (happened to me once with over 1,000 flags), and the impact is minimal. It doesn't seem quite right, but there are much more important issues to be addressed.

Comment: Normally edits cause _not an answer_ and _very low quality_ flags to be immediately marked helpful. This didn’t work for me recently for [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34520522/android-material-design-how-to-set-the-background-color-for-a-context-menu/34528771#34528771). A comment has linked to the [review item](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/10727051). The time stamps show that the answer has been edited substantially, but the review has continued _after the edit_, leading to a disputed flag. My first one after 278 helpful ones in a row.

Comment: I’ve actually very recently had two flags declined due to moderators apparently reviewing the related answers *after* users had already edited them. http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34609129/revisions (where the original—which is what I flagged—was clearly a non-answer) and http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34576085/revisions (which I flagged for attention before the user deleted the “ignore the clowns” part). I’m not losing any sleep over getting them declined (especially since the users did end up fixing the answers) but it does seem to suggest that maybe something isn’t working as expected.